# grid-template-columns that shrink and grow between a maximum and minimum pixel size

Tags: css, grid

I want grid columns that are a minimum of 200px and a maximum of 300px. I'm trying this, but the columns are always 300px.

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 300px));
```

I can make columns that shrink like this:

```
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
```

But then they get too big.

I've checked the [docs for minmax()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/minmax) and don't see an applicable example.

Is there a workaround for this?

See [The Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RichardU/y69x5rqo/4/)

**The Answer**

Important elements to the answer include changing to: `minmax(300px, auto));` as well as adding `box-sizing: border-box;`

Without those, the grid is not centered when it's down to one column.

Thanks!

Comment: if you set a max-width on the children, it might help and stick to your needs  :  https://jsfiddle.net/jyk34ez9/1

Comment: That works, although I'm not sure why. If you want to set that up as an answer, I will mark it solved. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use minmax(200px,1fr)or minmax(200px,auto)  and then max-width on the children themselves to avoid them grow bigger than 300px.

possible examples

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box
}

body {
  padding: 20px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
}
/* sizing */
.wrapper {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, 1fr));
}
.wrapper.bis {
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit, minmax(200px, auto));
}

.box {
  max-width: 300px
}
/* --- */
.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 10px;
}

.box {
  background-color: #20262e;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  max-width: 300px
}

.box {
  /* Demo see average width by chunks of 50px bg-gradient-color */
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(to right, red 0 50px, green 50px 100px);
  background-position: 0 0;
  background-repeat: repeat-x;
  background-size: auto 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="box a">A - 200px,1FR</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
</div>
<hr>
<div class="wrapper bis">
  <div class="box a">A - 200px,AUTO</div>
  <div class="box b">B</div>
  <div class="box c">C</div>
  <div class="box d">D</div>
  <div class="box e">E</div>
  <div class="box f">F</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks. In this case I literally needed to think inside the box.

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and I inspect element in my browser,and I think this is correct.because you use `padding` in each of these boxes.

this when using max value:
[image]

this when using the minimal value:[image]

Comment: Removing padding has no effect on the problem.